# express-http-proxy - handle form-data and body request nodejs

Tags: node.js, http-proxy, api-gateway, express-http-proxy

I have created a nodejs gateway server, in which based on url prefix, it proxy using `express-http-proxy:1.5.1` to many other microservices like this

```
this.router.all(Routes.ABC, httpProxy(baseUrl.XYZ, {
    parseReqBody: false,
  }));
```

now one of my ms has apis that holds `form-data` for that matter i need to set

```
parseReqBody : false
```

now if i do this, it will stop parsing `body` for other apis on the same ms.

I tried passing function to this `parseReqBody` so that based on `Content-Type` header i can set it to true or false.

But it does not accept function, it needs direct `boolean` value.

I want to make this prop false if there is form data otherwise it should parse the body.

And is there any way to work both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved my problem

```
const isMultipartRequest = function (req: Request) {
  const contentTypeHeader = req.headers['content-type']
  return contentTypeHeader && contentTypeHeader.indexOf('multipart') > -1
}

const proxy = function (host: string) {
  return function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    let reqBodyEncoding
    let reqAsBuffer = false
    let parseReqBody = true

    if (isMultipartRequest(req)) {
      reqAsBuffer = true
      reqBodyEncoding = null
      parseReqBody = false
    }
    return default_proxy(host, {
      reqAsBuffer,
      reqBodyEncoding,
      parseReqBody
    })(req, res, next)
  }
}

app.all(/widget/, proxy('localhost:3002'))
```